# Express $(0, 1)$ as the union of a sequence of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider$(a,b)=\cup^\infty_{n=2}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$

$\cup^\infty_{n=2}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$ is a closed cover of $[a,b]$

Thus, $(0,1)=\cup^\infty_{n=2}[0+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]=[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\cup[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]\cup[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]\cup[\frac{1}{5},\frac{4}{5}]...\cup(0,1)$

Comment: We have $[1/2,1)=[1/2,3/4]\cup[3/4,7/8]\cup\cdots$. Can you do a similar thing for $(0,1/2]$?

Comment: $\epsilon_1$ doesn't exist, between any two real numbers there is a real number between them.

Comment: @kingW3, I understand. That's my problem. Instead, should I denote $\epsilon_1$ as inf${(0,1)}$ ? Would that be better?

Comment: If $\epsilon_1=\inf((0,1))$ then $\epsilon_1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Part answer, part hint, but not a complete answer**

Your suspicion is correct: it's almost completely incorrect. That's partly because there's is no "smallest positive number greater than zero", for if $b$ were such a number, then $b/2$ would have to be either (a) not postive, or (b) not greater than zero, and neither of these is consistent with the rules of algebra.

As a hint: rather than writing *adjacent* closed intervals, you might try NESTED ones, ones that  stack up like nested measuring cups, so to speak. You could start with the interval $[1/2, 1/2]$, for instance.

Comment: By nested intervals, are you referring to open covers?

Comment: The interval $[1, 3]$ is "nested within" the interval $[0, 6]$ because every point of the former lies in the latter, i.e., the former is a subset of the latter. As a larger example, the intervals $I_n=[-n, n]$ are nested as well: each $I_n$ is a subset of $I_k$ for every $k > n$.